# Filter JSON field django with greater than, less than and a range using _contains

Tags: json, django, postgresql, django-models, filter

Let's say that I have this model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And then in the console:

```
>>Item.objects.create(data={'size': 11})
>>Item.objects.create(data={'size': 12})
>>Item.objects.create(data={'size': 13})
```

How  can I filter the results passing JSON data as follow but with the size in a range of numbers, and greater or less than a number?

```
Item.objects.filter(data__contains={'size': *match this numbers*})
```

Or is there any other way not using `data__size__gte` so i can create JSON variables and filter them with freedom.

Comment: Database design. Such extensive searching and filtering is not recommended with JSONField

Comment: What can be an alternative?

Comment: A properly normalized database

Comment: But looking at postgres JSON field you can filter the same with something such as:

`SELECT * FROM Item WHERE data @> '{}' AND data ->> 'size' > '11';`

Comment: I never said you couldn't i said it isn't suited o extensive querying.

Comment: The problem with a normalized database is that I will have many different items with different data so I can't create a model for each one

Comment: you are probably better of using a non relational database then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I solved the problem some time ago and a notification remembered me this question. The solution is simple. Yo can create a function that generate a dictionary of parameters to pass to the filter function.
In my project I use json fields to save some data for a product according to the category, so for different categories I create different forms.

Suppose I have a category called computers and I want to filter the products in the category "computers" according to the size of the ram.

```
dict_of_parameters = {"attributes__ram__gte": 2, "attributes__ram__lte": 8}
items = Product.objects.filter(**dict_of_parameters)  #  The ** operator will pass the dictionary as parameters to the function
```

Tips:

To generate the dictionary of parameters you have a lot of options. In my case I have a field in the category that contains a dictionary of fields useful to generate items and to filter them. A json field, something like

```
some_category.attributes = {"fields":
                                   {
                                    "ram":
                                         {
                                          "type": "number",
                                          "filter_by": ["gte", "lte"]
                                         }
                                    "CPU":
                                         {
                                          "type": "select",
                                          "options": ["I3", "I5", "I7"]
                                         }
                                   }
                            }
```

However you don't have to save this in a database, you can save it in a json file or whatever you want. From here you can create a function that generate a form from this fields and use it to generate the dictionary to pass to the filter function.

This gives you the flexibility of save data in json format in a Postgre database and filter that data even if you don't know the name of fields or you create new fields.

Comment: If there is any error please let me know. Also the model of attributes for categories is not perfect, this is just an example. If you need to know how to generate a form from a dictionary let me know, it took me some time to figure out how to do it and I couldn't find a solution in internet... So if there is no an answer out there of how to do it I will post the answer to generate a GenericForm in other post and save some time to other people.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Postgres and a recent version of Django, this can be done using the the `JSONField` from `contib.postgres.fields`:

```
Item.objects.filter(data__size=12)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield

If your queries get more complex, I would use a related model rather than than a `JSONField` so you can use the ORM.

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid. Using _contains yo have the freedom of create any variable and filter it and that is what I need.